# Code inside get not running after using express.static

Tags: node.js, http, express, server

This is my nodejs express setting:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile('public/index.html')
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});


module.exports = app;
```

I found out that when it use:

> app.use(express.static('public'));

Nothing runs inside this `get`:

> app.get('*', function (req, res) {
>           // nothing runs here
>         res.sendfile('public/index.html')
>       });

ps: I want to redirect (http -> https) inside that `get`.

Comment: What route are you trying?  And, does it have a matching file in your `public` directory?  `express.static()` will only handle things if it finds a matching file.  I don't know what your http -> https part of your question is about because you show no code to do that anywhere.

Comment: public is a folder which my webpack generated. I'm sure that it matches totally. I need to do something in app.get callback function ex: redirect http -> https. But the code inside that get function never runs. why..?

Comment: As I already said, if `express.static()` matches the route, then it will handle it and no request handlers that come after it will see the request.  If you want something to run before the `express.static()` line, then perhaps you want an `app.use()` middleware handler BEFORE the `express.static()` line.  You don't show any code that has anything to do with https so I still have no idea what that is about.

Comment: ok, I see.. I need to add "app.use()" middleware before express.static() , this middleware can redirect http to https.. right !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect all http requests to https, then insert an `app.use()` middleware as the first request handler with the redirect logic to https.  Express processes request handlers in the order you define them and you will want this middleware to be processed first before your `express.static()` middleware.

You will, of course, need to put all your other request handlers on an https server (not on the http server) so the https server can process your URLs after the redirect (something your code does not show).